# Django - Not able to get specific data from Model to the View

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

A bit stuck on getting specific data out from the Model via "POST" to the view. only want the IP to be "POST" back to the view.

Here is my function that get post data from the webpage. It gets the data fine but all i want is a single item from the specific row. It is not letting me change the html as I get the following error i change option value in html to " ipofnode.ip_address_field " from "ipofnode.id"

" Field 'id' expected a number but got '192.168.1.1'. "

If i keep it to "ipofnode.id" , it prints out the entire row on the webpage just fine. I only want the IP to be "POST" back to the view so i can save it as a string and pass it.

1: 192.168.0.216:R1-ISP:VMX

```
def inventory(request):
if request.method == "POST":
ipnode = Nodes.objects.get(pk=request.POST["ipofnode"])
#savedip = ipnode.ip_address_field.all()
listip.append(ipnode)
return render(request, "hwinventory/hwinventory.html",{
"allnodesips":Nodes.objects.all()})
```

hwinventory.html

```
{%extends "home/layout.html"%}
{% block body%}
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Inventory Check</h1>
<form action="{% url 'inventory' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<select name="ipofnode">
{% for ipofnode in allnodesips %}
<option value="{{ ipofnode.id }}">{{ipofnode.hostname}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<a href="{% url 'resultsinventory' %}">View Results</a>
{%endblock%}
```

MODEL

```
class Nodes(models.Model):
ip_address_field = models.GenericIPAddressField()
hostname= models.CharField(max_length=30)
device_type= models.CharField(max_length=30,default='')
def __str__(self):
return f"{self.ip_address_field}:{self.hostname}:{self.device_type}"
```

Comment: Spacing/Indendation is fine and it is rendering hwinventory/hwinventory.html.
in my model there are three columns. 

ip_address_field = models.GenericIPAddressField()

hostname= models.CharField(max_length=30)

device_type= models.CharField(max_length=30,default='')

I want to only get ip_address_field as POST data to the inventory view. I dont want to return anything from this return back. I want to save it in a variable and use it another function.

Comment: Please add second html and second view function to get all idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your question.

I've changed some variables name with underlining.

html

```
{% block body%}
    <h1 style="text-align:center;">Inventory Check</h1>

    <form action="{% url 'inventory' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <select name="ip_of_node">
            {% if all_nodes_ips %}
                {% for ip_of_node in all_nodes_ips %}
                    <option value="{{ ip_of_node.id }}">{{ip_of_node.hostname}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                <p>We haven't 'all_nodes_ips'</p>
            {% endif %}
        </select>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    {% if ip_of_node %}
        <p>{{ ip_of_node.ip_address_field }}</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>We haven't 'ip_of_node'</p>
    {% endif %}

    <a href="{% url 'results_inventory' %}">View Results</a>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
def inventory(request):
    all_nodes_ips = Nodes.objects.all()

    if request.method == "POST":
        ip_of_node = request.POST["ip_of_node"]
        data = Nodes.objects.filter(id=ip_of_node)
        context = {
            "ip_of_node": ip_of_node[0],
        }
        return render(request, "hw_inventory/hw_inventory.html", context)

    return render(request, "hw_inventory/hw_inventory.html", {"all_nodes_ips": all_nodes_ips})
```

In case you need to use new variable: it depends where and how you need to use it.
May be you should add forms.py and save it in db with .save() method.
In html above I've returned this variable on page.

Hope it could help.

Comment: See how do I write a good answer and that too with explanation [answer].

Comment: Thanks!, this helped resolved the issue.